# Strange favicon on Angular & Spring Boot App

Tags: javascript, html, angular, spring-boot, favicon

I have a Spring Boot Application with Angular on the front-end, I created a favicon in the static folder but when I load the page, a strange Icon apears:

![favicon][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbtQS.png

Above my import HTML line:

`<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />`

Does anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: I found the solution, the problem was happening because I was using resource filter on maven in the wrong way, I stoped do filtering on the full project and I did the filtering only in the index.html then it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I am using maven to build the application, I added a filter to on my index page, but I forgot to make it not filter other files, and this was making my favcicon to look strange, I fixed the pom excluding the files that I wanted to fix to filter, and then i included then, filtering it.

```
<resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>false</filtering>
    <excludes>
        <exclude>static/index.html</exclude>
            <exclude>application.properties</exclude>
        </excludes>
</resource>
<resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
    <includes>
        <include>static/index.html</include>
        <include>application.properties</include>
    </includes>
</resource>
```

Answer (score 0):

Force the favicon refreshing by doing

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico?v=2" />
```